# Postgres data path mapping from container to host - data directory on host is empty

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I was configuring postgres in docker container, when i'm mapping /var/lib/postgresql/data to directory ./data in project directory, this directory is locked and empty.

I was checking this directory in docker container, and all files are included in it.

When i do mapping data to virtual volume everything works fine pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data

This works fine:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
    pgsql: ~
    mongo: ~

...
    pgsql:
        container_name: "pgsql"
        hostname: "pgsql"
        image: "postgres:9.5"
        volumes:
            - "pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
        environment:
            - "POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}"
            - "POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}"
            - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}"
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
```

But when i do

```
version: "3"

volumes:
    pgsql: ~
    mongo: ~

...
    pgsql:
        container_name: "pgsql"
        hostname: "pgsql"
        image: "postgres:9.5"
        volumes:
            - "./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
        environment:
            - "POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}"
            - "POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}"
            - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}"
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
```

data directory on host is empty.

I remember that the same thing was working in MySQL, the reason that i want to map data to physical directory is that i want to use docker on production, and i'd like to store data in virtual volume and also in directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it empty or locked? (locked is normal since folder permissions on the host are inherited from the ones in the container) : try to run `sudo ls ./data`.

Comment: It's both, empty and locked

Comment: Does `./data` exist before starting service `pgsql`? If so, remove it, and let `docker` create the folder when starting `pgsql` (with the right permissions).

Comment: I have tried both ways with precreated directory and directory created by docker

Comment: Just tested your `docker-compose.yml` on a Ubuntu host, it works. It may be permissions issues on the current folder (`.`), try to use `/tmp/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data` and check `/tmp/data` contents.

Comment: Ohhh really, writing it to tmp works, so for sure that's permissions problem